# Linux-MIPS syscall-saved registers?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, mips, system-calls

Which registers are saved across *syscalls* (not function calls, the actual round-trip to kernelspace via the `syscall` instruction) on Linux/MIPS?

Judging from the `RESTORE_SOME` macro in the `arch/mips/include/asm/stackframe.h` header, it looks like r2-r7, r25, r28, and r31 are restored, and of course callee-saved registers are automatically preserved by the calling convention even in kernelspace (any kernelspace function that's going to use them will save them itself before clobbering them). Is this correct?

Of course at least a couple (r2 and r7) will have their values clobbered with the result of the syscall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this link](http://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Syscall) for a description (the only one I'm aware of other than the kernel source itself) of register usage in Linux/MIPS system calls.

Comment: Thanks. BTW this was added to the wiki today; it did not exist when I asked.

Comment: I follow the linux-mips mailing list and happened to see mention of this new wiki entry this morning... good timing ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I guess that the [MIPS ABI](http://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/MIPS_ABI_History) Convention should define precisely what registers are containing the syscall number and arguments before the syscall, and what registers are containing the result (including error code) after the syscall. Often syscalls dont use the stack, only registers.

Answer (score 2):

"In keeping with the calling conventions, the syscall preserves the values of those registers that o32 defines as surviving function calls."
([See MIPS Run](http://www.scribd.com/doc/39654922/244/What-Happens-on-a-System-Call), page 379)